# How to use performSegue function correctly the view controller appears a few seconds?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue, uistoryboardsegue

[image]The current view controller has 3 buttons and their labels changing randomly so when the user presses a button I need to check the button label if it is correct I need to segue to some view controller and if it is wrong I need to segue to another view controller.

here is the code for one button the other buttons have similar code except for the variables names.

```
  @IBAction func click2(_ sender: Any) {

    if (opt2.titleLabel?.text) != nil {
        let userAnswer=opt2.titleLabel?.text;

        if ((userAnswer!.elementsEqual(self.optionsArray[0])) == true)
        {
            playSound(fileName: "kidsCheering")
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "sucessMessageSegue", sender: nil)
        }
        else {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "wrongMessgeSegue", sender: nil)
        }



        }
    }
```

this the code of one of the view controller that I'm segueing to and the other one is similar:
import UIKit

```
class wrongMessageViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }



}
```

this the error that i got from the terminal

Warning: Attempt to present Proximity.QuestionViewController: on Proximity.ViewController:  which is already presenting

Comment: click and drag, there is also upload symbol

Comment: @ReemaAlhassan what is your issue?

Comment: I wrote the description of my issue above please read it.

Comment: You haven’t given a detailed description of what is actually happening.

Comment: You haven't added what is your problem here

Comment: please post the two view controller codes that you are segueing to

Comment: Please share more code... your view controller should not be dismissing on its own unless you have told it to somewhere

Comment: Please also add in more code from your main view controller from where you segue from

Comment: How is your QuestionViewController being presented from the initial viewController? Which ViewController is initiating the segues?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT-----------------------------------

After more updates

You cannot present a view controller from a view controller that is already being presented so either use a different style of segue or handle it correctly.

Trying to present a UIViewController when another UIViewController is being presented all you have to do is dismiss the existing UIViewController and then present the new one

You can try something like this as well... 
Add this in on your mainViewController in ViewDidLoad()

```
definesPresentationContext = true
```

UPDATE----------

Have you tried doing something like this

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

    if ViewController.isActive == true {

        ViewController.isActive = false

    }
}
```

or like this..

```
self.searchController.dismiss(animated: false) { 
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "<YOUR SEGUE IDENTIFIER>", sender: cell)
}
```

or adding this in where you take the action to segue

```
if searchController.isActive {
    self.searchController.dismiss(animated: false) { 
        // Do what you want here like perform segue or present
    }
}
```

This is basically the same as the others..this goes in to where you take action to segue

```
if presentedViewController == nil {
     self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
} else{
      self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false) { () -> Void in
           self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
      }
}
```

You can try adding in a dispatch main... but it is not best practice to do so

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) {
     //dismiss and present new one
}
```

Comment: There is no issue with the array it works fine. I used the array because I have many questions and answers so this is the only way to do it as far as I know and I tested it and it works fine. my issue is with the pefromSegue function as it presents the next view controller for a few seconds only and then the previous view controller come back again.

Comment: post the code for the view controllers in which you are segueing to

Comment: when you perfrom a segue it should not dismiss itself unless you have specified it to

Comment: if let titleLabel = op2.titleLabel, let text = titleLabel.text, !text.isEmpty {
      if text == "condition1" { 
      }
}

Comment: post the code in your quesion, make an edit and post the view controller code that you are pushing to... the code that controllers the other 2 view controllers

Comment: Nope, I haven't answer his question, I have just written your code's cleaner version. @JulianSilvestri

Comment: actually, I didn't put any code in the segueing view controller it has only an empty viewDidLoad() function. I wrote the text that I want in the storyboard itself.  do you think this the problem because the there is no code?

Comment: @ReemaAlhassan your controllers should not be dismissing themselves unless you  have told them to.. please share more code in your question

Comment: i will upload it above

Comment: Warning: Attempt to present <Proximity.QuestionViewController: 0x10c072750>  on <Proximity.ViewController: 0x10490c090> which is already presenting <Proximity.QuestionViewController: 0x10c00b500>.    this the error that i got from the terminal

Comment: I know what you said and I have tried a million ways including the dismiss of the current view controller and it is not working, unfortunately .. thank for your help

Comment: I have tried your first and third and fourth answers .. and the result: the first one nothing change. and  when I press the button the current view dismissed and no segueing view controller appear

Comment: but i couldn't understand the second answer do you mean by search controller the current controller?

Comment: oh sorry That shouldnt be search controller it should be yourViewController

Comment: Value of type 'QuestionViewController' has no member 'isActive' i got this error

Comment: do not use the view controller you want to go to in viewDidDissapear, use the main view Controller that you are leaving. In viewDidDissapear you use the viewController you are currently on and when that view is dissapearing the function fires